# Specifing an image using JavaScript (choosing it randomly)

Tags: javascript, html

Hello guys :) I was trying to randomly generate an image from the list of variables, but nothing is working. I tried something like this:

```
document.querySelector("img").src = variables.img;
```

It doesn't work though, because it changes the first image on my site, not the one i want it to change. I have a list made like that:

```
var songs =
[
    { filename: "http://linktomp3-1.com", title: "title1", album: "---" },
    // Song: title1
    { filename: "http://linktomp3-2.com", title: "title2", album: "---" },
    // Song: title2
    { filename: "http://linktomp3-3.com", title: "title3", album: "---" },
    // Song: title3
    { filename: "http://linktomp3-4.com", title: "title4", album: "---" },
];
    var randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * songs.length);
    var song = songs[randomIndex];
    document.querySelector("source").src = song.filename;
    document.getElementById("songTitle").textContent = song.title;
    document.getElementById("songAlbum").textContent = song.album;
```

And here is table before the text:

```
<table width="300">
       <tr>
            <td width="190">
            <b>Made by:</b> <span>Band Title</span><br>
            <b>Title:</b> <span id='songTitle'></span><br><br>
            <b>Album:</b> <span id='songAlbum'></span>
            </td>

            <td width="10">
            </td>
<td width="100">
<img src="http://www.someimg.com/someimg.jpg"></img>
</td>
       </tr>
</table>

<br><br>

<audio class="audio-element" controls="true" preload="none" loop="loop">

<!-- Adding audio sources -->

            <source src="mp3file.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" />
            <br>
            <b>Your outdated browser does not support HTML5. <br>
            Get Mozilla Firefox <a href="https://www.mozilla.org/pl/firefox/new/"> >HERE< </a></b>

</audio>
```

Is there any way to specify the image i want to change using Javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give the image you want to change an ID so you can target it specifically, as you did with your spans.

```
<td width="100">
    <img id="bandImg" src="http://www.someimg.com/someimg.jpg"></img>
</td>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/1b1nt95c/11/